# Zero-modified distribution of a Geometric variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ follow a Geometric distribution with probability of success $0.1$, or $X\sim G(0.1)$. How do I calculate the probability that the zero-modified
distribution of $X$ with $f^M_X (0) = 0.3$ is less than $4$?

Comment: As there are two common alternative definitions for 'the Geometric' distribution, your question is not uniquely defined.

Comment: Fair enough. Let $\Pr (X=x)$ be the number of failures prior to a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordinary geometric distribution $Y$ with parameter $0.1$ has $\Pr(Y=k)=(0.9)^{k-1}(0.1)$ for $k\ge 1$.

We assume that by the zero-modified distribution $X$ you mean that $\Pr(X=0)=0.3$ and that for for $k\ge 1$, we have 
$$\Pr(X=k)=(0.7)\Pr(Y=k)=(0.7)(0.9)^{k-1}(0.1)\tag{1}$$
for $k\ge 1$.

We want $\Pr(X\lt 4)$. This is $\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+\Pr(X=3)$. The formula for calculating $\Pr(X=k)$ for $k\ge 1$ is given in (1).

Comment: Verified to be correct.